# Clutch pedal on 1995 VW Golf is sticking

Tags: clutch, vw

The clutch pedal on my 1995 VW Golf 'sticks' in the half-way-depressed position after I release my foot from the pedal.  I believe that the clutch is fully engaged (unclutched) at this point, but a little nudge from underneath is necessary for the pedal to spring to its fully undepressed position.  How should this be fixed?  Maybe just a little WD-40?

Answer (score 6):

Is the clutch cable operated or hydraulic?  On hydraulic clutches that's a common symptom of a failing master and/or slave cylinder(s).

Comment: IIRC, this car has a hydraulic clutch. this was my thought as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had this happened on an 1995 Passat and it was the slave cylinder which got replaced and problem fixed.